# Tensor Product: Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

*This question has been modified...*

**Problem**

Given Hilbert spaces.

In general, their algebraic tensor product isn't complete:
$$\mathcal{H}\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{K}=\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{K}\iff\dim\mathcal{H}<\infty\lor\dim\mathcal{K}<\infty$$
How to prove this from scratch?

**Attempt**

Choose orthonormal bases:
$$\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{T}:=\{\sigma\otimes\tau:\sigma\in\mathcal{S},\tau\in\mathcal{T}\}$$

One obtains some candidates:
$$\sigma_k\otimes\tau_l\in\mathcal{S}\otimes\mathcal{T}:\quad\sum_{kl=1}^\infty\frac{1}{kl}\sigma_k\otimes\tau_l\quad\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{kl}\delta_{kl}\sigma_k\otimes\tau_l$$
However the former one drops out:
$$\sum_{kl=1}^\infty\frac{1}{kl}\sigma_k\otimes\tau_l=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}\sigma_k\right)\otimes\left(\sum_{l=1}^\infty\frac{1}{l}\tau_l\right)$$
So it is not obvious at all wether the latter one works out!

**Reference**

Build-up on: [Vector Spaces: Tensor Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1074553/79762)

Comment: `Obviously, it is not complete yet.' Certainly it is complete because finite dimensional.

Comment: Come on, that was a typo, you could have known that!

Comment: So what is your question? Could you explain it?

Comment: Really it is not a good idea to modify your question so as to render obsolete any answer(s) thoughtfully provided. Better is to ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

That element you want to form is just an elementary tensor $x\otimes y$ in the algebraic tensor product $\mathcal H\otimes\mathcal H$. Then you want to have sums of those guys, and then limits of them.

Comment: Aaaah ok, so is it like this?: So if I would instead consider formally $\sum_{k,l}a_{k,l}e_k\otimes e_l$ then they're not necessarily of the form $\sum_{k,l}x_ky_le_k\otimes e_l$.

Comment: Yes. But a Hilbert space is in particular a complete Banach space. So you would have to argue that the formal space constructed like that is a complete Banach space with the norm induced by the inner product. It doesn't look simpler than taking the algebraic tensor product and completing it.

Comment: Sorry for the late come-back. I got my question now: Why is the algebraic tensor product of infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces incomplete yet: $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{H}\subsetneq\mathcal{H}\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{H}$ More specifically, can one construct a sequence in a general or in a special Hilbert space algebraic tensor product whos limit is certainly not contained: $z_n:=\sum_{1\leq k\leq K(n)}\sum_{1\leq l\leq L(n)}\alpha_n(i,j)s_n(i)\otimes s_n(j):\quad\|z_m-z_n\|\to0,z_n\nrightarrow z$

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I unaccept your answer, do you? Still I gave you: (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Let us choose orthonormal bases $\{e_i: i \in I\}$ of $\mathcal H$ and $\{f_j : j\in J \}$ of $\mathcal K$.

Assume $\mathcal K$ is finite dimensional, thus $J$ is finite. Let $x\in \mathcal H \hat\otimes \mathcal K$ and write it as
$$
x=\sum_{j\in J} x_j \otimes f_j \quad \text{with}\quad x_j =\sum_{i\in I} (e_i\otimes e_j, x) \, e_i\,,
$$
where $(\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,)$ is the scalar product to be chosen linear in the second argument.
This shows that $x\in \mathcal H\otimes \mathcal K$.

Conversely, if both are infnite dimensional, we can identify a subset of $I$ and $J$ with $\mathbb N$.
Then 
$$y=\sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \frac1{n!}e_n\otimes f_n \in \mathcal H\hat\otimes \mathcal K.
$$
Show that $y\not \in \mathcal H\otimes \mathcal K$.

Comment: Oh I forgot to answer: That is precisely I'm looking for. I tried similar constructions but couldn't figure it out. Can you explain why: $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n!}e_n\otimes f_n\notin\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{K}$

Comment: because if $x\in \mathcal H\otimes \mathcal K$ it is finite sum of elementary tensors not infinite. (sorry for my weak english in advanced)

Comment: I linked to this question and answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2157955 as I can't prove the last part.